# Angular 2 with webpack

Tags: node.js, angular

I am trying to set my angular2 project with webpack but after I run npm install its giving me below errors, I have imported everything from angular guide (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html):

```
chunk    {0} app.js (app) 1.98 kB {2} [rendered]
chunk    {1} polyfills.js (polyfills) 586 kB
chunk    {2} vendor.js (vendor) 2.47 MB {1}

ERROR in /Users/dheerajagrawal/newenv/backend/mycontactid/static/v4/beta/node_modules/@angular/core/testing/mock_application_ref.d.ts
(12,33): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
ERROR in /Users/dheerajagrawal/newenv/backend/mycontactid/static/v4/beta/node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.d.ts
(7,59): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
ERROR in /Users/dheerajagrawal/newenv/backend/mycontactid/static/v4/beta/node_modules/rxjs/observable/PromiseObservable.d.ts
(22,31): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
ERROR in /Users/dheerajagrawal/newenv/backend/mycontactid/static/v4/beta/node_modules/rxjs/observable/PromiseObservable.d.ts
(23,26): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
ERROR in /Users/dheerajagrawal/newenv/backend/mycontactid/static/v4/beta/node_modules/@angular/router/src/router.d.ts
(162,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
ERROR in /Users/dheerajagrawal/newenv/backend/mycontactid/static/v4/beta/node_modules/@angular/router/src/router.d.ts
(178,59): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
ERROR in /Users/dheerajagrawal/newenv/backend/mycontactid/static/v4/beta/node_modules/@angular/http/src/url_search_params.d.ts
(11,16): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in /Users/dheerajagrawal/newenv/backend/mycontactid/static/v4/beta/node_modules/@angular/http/src/headers.d.ts
(43,59): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in /Users/dheerajagrawal/newenv/backend/mycontactid/static/v4/beta/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/dom/dom_renderer.d.ts
(10,37): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.
ERROR in /Users/dheerajagrawal/newenv/backend/mycontactid/static/v4/beta/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/promise.d.ts
(13,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in /Users/dheerajagrawal/newenv/backend/mycontactid/static/v4/beta/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/async.d.ts
(27,33): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in /Users/dheerajagrawal/newenv/backend/mycontactid/static/v4/beta/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/lang.d.ts
(4,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in /Users/dheerajagrawal/newenv/backend/mycontactid/static/v4/beta/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/lang.d.ts
(5,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.

ERROR in /Users/dheerajagrawal/newenv/backend/mycontactid/static/v4/beta/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/collection.d.ts
(11,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in /Users/dheerajagrawal/newenv/backend/mycontactid/static/v4/beta/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/facade/collection.d.ts
(102,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.

ERROR in /Users/dheerajagrawal/newenv/backend/mycontactid/static/v4/beta/node_modules/@angular/common/src/facade/promise.d.ts
(9,38): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in /Users/dheerajagrawal/newenv/backend/mycontactid/static/v4/beta/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts
(4,39): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in /Users/dheerajagrawal/newenv/backend/mycontactid/static/v4/beta/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts
(7,9): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in /Users/dheerajagrawal/newenv/backend/mycontactid/static/v4/beta/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts
(8,30): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in /Users/dheerajagrawal/newenv/backend/mycontactid/static/v4/beta/node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/component_resolver.d.ts
(9,58): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in /Users/dheerajagrawal/newenv/backend/mycontactid/static/v4/beta/node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/component_resolver.d.ts
(13,49): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.

ERROR in /Users/dheerajagrawal/newenv/backend/mycontactid/static/v4/beta/src/app/app.component.ts
(5,13): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.

ERROR in /Users/dheerajagrawal/newenv/backend/mycontactid/static/v4/beta/src/app/app.component.ts
(6,12): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.

ERROR in ./src/polyfills.ts
(3,1): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.

ERROR in ./src/polyfills.ts
(4,5): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'process'.

ERROR in ./src/polyfills.ts
(9,3): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.

ERROR in ./src/main.ts
(4,5): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'process'.

ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../../public/css/styles.css in /Users/dheerajagrawal/newenv/backend/mycontactid/static/v4/beta/src/app
 @ ./src/app/app.component.js 12:0-38

ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.html
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../../public/images/angular.png in /Users/dheerajagrawal/newenv/backend/mycontactid/static/v4/beta/src/app
 @ ./src/app/app.component.html 1:93-135
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
    chunk    {0} index.html 301 bytes
webpack: bundle is now VALID.
```

my component file is:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import '../../public/css/styles.css';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: require('./app.component.html'),
  styles: [require('./app.component.css')]
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

typings.json

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160602141332",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160621224255",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160621231320"
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "angular2-webpack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Web app",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --port 8080",
    "test": "karma start",
    "build": "rimraf dist && webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js --progress --profile --bail",
    "postinstall": "typings install"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/forms": "0.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-alpha.8",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "0.6.12",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.15.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
    "karma": "^0.13.22",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.8",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "^1.7.0",
    "null-loader": "^0.1.1",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.7",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "ts-loader": "^0.8.1",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^1.0.4",
    "webpack": "^1.13.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.14.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: From the error what I see is you don't have your es2015 shims script loaded.

Comment: Can you please copy paste the contents of your typings.json file?

Comment: See this video, a step by step to integrate ng2 with webpack https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j9w5hFit5rM

Comment: Hi I have added typings.json & package.json please check